# Samsung G S3 Mini: UK Apps 'not available in your country'?: in UK, with new UK phone from UK provider!

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Just got my new Samsung Galaxy s3 mini, from t-mobile UK.

Trying to download UK apps (e.g. BBC News) from Google Play, but getting the "app not available in your country" messages....

Am in the UK, using UK wi-fi and EE, my google account is and always was registered to the UK. There's a bit written about moving country, but nothing that has worked to resolve my issue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM or stock?

Comment: Have you registered a credit card in Google Play yet? If so, what country is it from?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130597/this-item-is-not-available-in-your-country/216830#216830

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried turning it on and off again? If it doesn't work, take it back to the shop.