# This item is not available in your country

Tags: google-play-store

I am trying to install an app available freely in switzerland (postcard creator).

Use a VPN that connects to switzerland (I actually am in colombia).

I used google wallet with a swiss visa card to buy an item in the play store.

i deleted app data in app settings. I cleared cache.

Still the same problem.

I am running android lollipop

Comment: Have you tried spoofing your GPS location as well? I am not sure if that will affect it, but it might be worth a try

Comment: yes... had no effect at all

Answer (score 2):

[Google Play support says:](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en)

> - You can only change your Play country once per year.
> - When you change your country, you won’t be able to use your Google Play balance that you have in your old country in your new country.

So, avoid Google Play and use another market app. I suggest either:

- [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/apkpure/com.apkpure.aegon)
- [Aptiode](https://aptoide.en.aptoide.com)

Both allow auto-updating apps.